# iOS retina safari bug rendering border radius?

Tags: css, ios, html, webkit, mobile-safari

Using the following css, I get a slight jagged or non-smooth circle rendered in the iOS webview browser.  Anyone know of a fix?  It shows up at any border width, and can event be detected as low as 1px with the high density retina display on the iPhone.

```
a.circle {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10000;
    border: 6px solid #000;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #ccc;
    width:54px;
    height:54px;
    top:352px;
    left:123px;
    border-radius: 99px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

a.circle:active {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
```

Notice the slight hard and somewhat angled lines on both the border and inner 1px shadow:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://www.css-101.org/articles/-webkit-transform-rotate-and-anti-aliasing/rotate-creates-jagged-border-image.php

This is a slightly different issue, but it directly relates to iOS.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at that article and tried the fix, although the issue does not appear to be the same.  I'm still looking for a fix.